# Erratic timeout when using TCP sockets locally on macOS

Tags: macos, sockets, tcp, bsd

I'm getting an occasional timeout error (ETIMEDOUT) when connecting to another program on the same machine (127.0.0.1). The relevant code is the following:

```
   do
   {
          fl=connect(mysocket, addr, len);
          if (fl != 0)
            usleep(wait *= 2);
   }
   while (fl == -1 && (errno == ETIMEDOUT));
```

I'm primarily developing on Linux, and the same code run in the same manner never produces this error. I find this really confusing because I cannot imagine any delays when connecting locally, and my understanding is that if the host port was unavailable, the error would be ECONNREFUSED.

Comment: You can't do this. Any connect failure makes the socket unusable: you have to close it and create a new one and connect that.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by user207421, the standard says that a socket is in an undefined state after a failed connection attempt. Linux will allow to continue but macOS does not, so the solution is closing the socket and creating new one.

Comment: What standard? Does Linux really behave like this? Evidence?

Comment: I can confirm the Linux behaviour for ECONNREFUSED because that's easy to test. The man page also hints at Linux acting differently: "If connect() fails, consider the state of the socket as unspecified.  Portable applications should close the socket and create a new one for reconnecting."